# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error when importing csv file

Tags: python, pandas, summarization

I am having a very frustrating time trying to import the wikihow dataset.

Basically my data looks like this

[image]

And I am getting the following error when trying to import it

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 14>()
12
13 # Read in the CSV file
---> 14 wikihow_eng_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/COSC420 Task One/wikihowAll.csv',  delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8', error_bad_lines=False)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 4974

My code looks like this

wikihow_eng_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/COSC420 Task One/wikihowAll.csv',  delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8', error_bad_lines=False)

why is this so hard? please help someone.

Comment: How about using the parameter engine=’python’ in read_csv?

Comment: Try to add `quoting=3` to `pd.read_csv`

Comment: That allows me to import the dataset however there is significant data loss now my data looks like this index headline title text
0 " null null
1 Keep related supplies in the same area. NaN null
2 Make an effort to clean a dedicated workspace after every session. NaN null so the title and text feilds are empty

Comment: Can you share your file?

Comment: You can download the csv from here https://ucsb.app.box.com/s/ap23l8gafpezf4tq3wapr6u8241zz358

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? It seems `error_bad_lines` has been deprecated since `1.3` which suggests you're using an old version? Your data loads properly for me on latest pandas `2.0.1` (Note: it's a **590mb** file.)